# Gauge constraint in the definition of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ invariant

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, berry-pancharatnam-phase

[Cross-posted at MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11715/5).

In Fu and Kane's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0606336) from 2006, the authors define the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ invariant for time-reversal invariant topological insulators as an obstruction to Stoke's theorem,
$$
\begin{equation}
\nu=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\oint_{\partial\text{HBZ}}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{k})-\int_{\text{HBZ}}\mathrm{d}^2\mathbf{k}F(\mathbf{k})\right]\text{(mod 2)},
\end{equation}
$$
where $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{k})=\sum_{n,\sigma}\langle u_{n,\sigma}(\mathbf{k})|\mathrm{i}\nabla|u_{n,\sigma}(\mathbf{k})\rangle$ and $F=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{k})$ (where $|u_{n,\sigma}(\mathbf{k})\rangle$s are the periodic Bloch functions). The integrals are evaluated over half of the Brillouin zone. This formula is not gauge invariant and the authors impose a time reversal constraint on the periodic Bloch functions,
$$
\begin{equation}
|u_{n,\uparrow}(-\mathbf{k})\rangle=\Theta|u_{n,\downarrow}(\mathbf{k})\rangle
\end{equation}
$$
$$
\begin{equation}
|u_{n,\downarrow}(-\mathbf{k})\rangle=-\Theta|u_{n,\uparrow}(\mathbf{k})\rangle
\end{equation}.
$$
However, I do not understand how this fixes the gauge. I can always define the new Bloch states,

$$
\begin{equation}
|u_{n,\uparrow}(\mathbf{k})\rangle'=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta_{\mathbf{k}}}|u_{n,\uparrow}(\mathbf{k})\rangle
\end{equation}
$$
$$
\begin{equation}
|u_{n,\downarrow}(\mathbf{k})\rangle'=\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\theta_{-\mathbf{k}}}|u_{n,\downarrow}(\mathbf{k})\rangle
\end{equation}
$$
which satisfies the gauge constraint for any arbitrary choice of $\theta_{\mathbf{k}}$. The Berry connection gets modified to,
$$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{k})\rightarrow\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{k})+\nabla(\theta_{\mathbf{k}}-\theta_{-\mathbf{k}}).
\end{equation}
$$
If I choose a $\theta$ that has a singularity in only one-half of the Brillouin zone, it can change the value of $\nu$ by 1. My question is, do we need any additional constraints on the Bloch functions to define $\nu$ unambiguously modulo 2? Thank you!

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, but if $\theta_\mathbf k$ is singular at some $\mathbf k_0$ then $\theta_\mathbf k -\theta_{-\mathbf k}$ is singular at both $\mathbf k_0$ and $-\mathbf k_0$, no?

Comment: @J.Murray Indeed there will be a singularity at $\mathbf{k}_0$ and $-\mathbf{k}_0$, however only one of them will lie inside the HBZ, therefore when you integrate over the HBZ, the singularity at $\mathbf{k}_0$ will contribute and change the value of $\nu$ by 1.

Comment: I suppose I don't really understand the question. To which term in your first expression is your gauge transformation meant to contribute? $F$ is gauge invariant, and the gradient of a scalar function vanishes under a closed loop integral. Are you imagining that your $\theta$'s have some kind of branch cut singularity that intersects the integration path?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to understand what happens when $\theta$ has a branch cut. For example, if we choose $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$, the integral of $\nabla\theta$ around a contour encircling the origin will give us 1.

Comment: Sorry, the integral around a contour encircling the origin will give us $2\pi$.

Comment: Well, you can’t just integrate over a branch cut, because the Berry connection isn’t defined there. The Stokes’ theorem, through which the concept of this kind of obstruction is essentially defined, assumes that both $A$ and $F$ are well-defined on the domains over which they’re being integrated.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, upon a gauge transformation, we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{k})\rightarrow\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{k})+\nabla(\theta_{\mathbf{k}}-\theta_{-\mathbf{k}}).
\end{equation}
so $\nu$ is changed by
\begin{align}
\Delta\nu & =\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{\partial\text{HBZ}}\nabla(\theta_{\mathbf{k}}-\theta_{-\mathbf{k}})\\
& = 2\cdot \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{\partial\text{HBZ}}\nabla\theta_{\mathbf{k}}
\end{align}
where the loop integral is the winding of $\theta_{\bf k}$ and yield integer multiple of $2\pi$ thus $\Delta \nu$ gives 0 mod 2.